# Web Browser ActiveX control error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am getting this message (attached) that says:

> An ActiveX control on this page is not safe.  Your current security
>   settings prohibit running unsafe controls on this page. As a result
>   this page might not display as intended.

I have ArcGIS version 10, and installed it on Windows 7, 32 bit.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you provide a public url that produces this message?

Comment: What application is this coming from... ArcGIS Server? Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know arcgis, however the solution for this kind of IE messages is to add the host to the trusted sites zone to allow ActiveX objects to be executed in the webpage.